Stepping into Library Code Appears in Green Pointer and Keeps Stepping Out
I am trying to debug a Flask app with VS Code using the following configuration in my launch.json:
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python Debugger: Flask",
            "type": "debugpy",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "flask",
            "env": {
                "FLASK_APP": "app.py",
                "FLASK_DEBUG": "1"
            },
            "args": [
                "run",
                "--no-debugger",
                "--no-reload"
            ],
            "jinja": true,
            "autoStartBrowser": false,
            "justMyCode": false
        }
    ]
}

When I try to step into library code, the relevant files do not open up automatically, I have to Ctrl + click to open them myself and when I do the pointer appears green. When I try to step over or step into within these library files, I keep being sent back to the my application code (app.py).
Here is an example of what I see when I try to step into the load_dotenv() function from python-dotenv:

Note: This is not the actual code I am trying to debug, but I just wanted to show an example. I want to debug my own library code.
What is going on here? I have not experienced this before.
UPDATE: I just realized that this is happening when I try to debug library code in any of my projects; not just the Flask app.

Downgrading VSCode to 1.89.1 did it for me. Good luck!
